# Filling a div without overflowing it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this layout

[image]

Inside the side columns, col2 and col3, I have a div inside, each being a holder. I need to fill those holders with other divs of different sizes without overflowing vertically the holders. So i need to calculate how many divs i can put in until there's no more space or when the next div is going to overflow the holder.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Ordinarily, it's common practice to allow columns like this to expand downward as far as they need to, as long as doing so doesn't break the layout.  Do you have a live demo we could look at?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the *width* of the div to the *scrollwidth* of its container. If the scrollwidth is bigger than the width, you're overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some javascript to get the height of the divs, then work from there. Or add an overflow css property (with a set height) so that the inner content will never stretch the outer div.